# I can't get second loop deep ampscript to populate?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to build a report based off of the _Jobs and _Clicks (and eventually opens an such but anyway)
So this report I've got a data extension that has all the _Jobs from the past month.  That's the first loop.  Everything works and fills out the information I'm going for, but then I create a second loop and I'm trying to get all the link names to list (and eventually the counts for unique and total), but I can't get the link names to work it just shows up as blank?

```
<h4>Click Aggregation Email</h4>
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i, @JobID, @DeliveredTime, @EmailName, @EmailSubject, @SalesForceTotalSubscriberCount 

set @lookupValue = "1"

set @rows = LookupRows("DV_Jobs_One_Off","RETURN", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

FOR @i = 1 TO @rowCount DO

set @row = row(@rows,@i)
set @JobID = field(@row,"JobID")
set @EmailName = field(@row,"EmailName")
set @DeliveredTime = field(@row,"DeliveredTime")
set @EmailSubject = field(@row,"EmailSubject")
set @SalesForceTotalSubscriberCount = field(@row,"SalesForceTotalSubscriberCount")

]%%
<table border="1" width="600">
<tr><td width="200">JobID is </td><td>%%=v(@JobID)=%%</td></tr>
<tr><td width="200">EmailName is </td><td>%%=v(@EmailName)=%%</td></tr>
<tr><td width="200">DeliveredTime is </td><td>%%=v(@DeliveredTime)=%%</td></tr>
<tr><td width="200">EmailSubject is </td><td>%%=v(@EmailSubject)=%%</td></tr>
<tr><td width="200">SalesForceTotalSubscriberCount is </td><td>%%=v(@SalesForceTotalSubscriberCount)=%%</td></tr>
</table>
<table border="1" width="600">
<tr><td width="500">Link Name</td><td width="50">Total</td><td width="50">Unique</td></tr>
%%[
var @rowsL, @rowL, @rowCountL, @lookupValueLinks, @j, @URL, @LinkName, @LinkContent, @IsUnique, @previousLinkName, @rowsClick, @rowsDaily
set @lookupValueLinks = @JobID

set @rowsL = LookupOrderedRows("DV_Clicks_Daily_Distinct", 0, "LinkName asc", "JobID", @lookupValueLinks)
set @rowCountL = rowcount(@rowsL)
set @previousLinkName = ''

FOR @j = 1 TO @rowCountL DO

set @rowL = row(@rowsL,@j)
set @LinkName = field(@rowL,"LinkName")
set @URL = field(@rowL,"URL")
set @rowCountUnique = rowcount(LookupRows("DV_Clicks_Daily_Distinct","URL", @URL))

IF EMPTY(@previousLinkName) OR @LinkName != @previousLinkName THEN
 SET @previousLinkName = @LinkName

]%%
<tr><td><%%=v(@LinkName)=%%</td><td>%%=v(@rowCountUnique)=%%</td><td>Unique</td></tr> 
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
%%[ next @j ]%%
</table>
Total Clicks is %%=v(@rowCountL)=%%
%%[ next @i ]%%
```

Data Extension
[image: Data Extension is limited to one JobID for testing but all fields populated with something]

[image: Send Preview of populated data]

Answer (score 3):

You have a logic issue. On the first iteration of you @j loop @previousLinkName will be set to "empty" as the value of the current link name does not equal "empty". Any further links either are null/empty or don't equal "empty".

Comment: Whoops.  I was messing around and questioning my logic.  I would still expect the loop for the link names would still be a string of "empty" for each iteration, but it still came up with nothing at all just a literal empty table data cell.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I'd expect, too. Any chance of a screenshot of the data in your DEs?

Comment: I edited the original code to the correct code (or last code I had), and added some images of the output.  Thanks for your help.